# Disable the div plus change the cursor

Tags: html, css

I have `div` element which I need to disable. So I have defined the following **CSS** class for it:

```
.hideDiv {
    pointer-events: none;
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

While the first line of the CSS class works fine, the second line does not. Can you help me with this?

Please note that I need to get this work on Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pointer-events: none` will effectively stop mouse interactions with `.hideDiv`. This means that the action of hovering over the div will also be prevented, thus making the cursor not appear.

Instead, you can wrap your `.hideDiv` in another div, and add the cursor property to the outer/parent div.

See example below:

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent {
  cursor: not-allowed;
}

.hideDiv {
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Remove pointer-events: none and the below css works */
.hideDiv:hover {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent box">
  <div class="box hideDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```